# Android app never fully uninstall - SQLite database remains

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using a sqlite database as an asset in my Android project that I'm trying to manually update, but my older version always comes back.

On my Pixel 5 I tried to:

- Delete the app before reinstalling from Visual Studio debugger.
- Go in the phone's storage, find the app and delete cache and data, then proceed to uninstall and finally reinstall from Visual Studio.
- Reboot the phone after uninstalling.

In Visual Studio I tried to:

- Cleaning entire solution & rebuilding it after deleting older database and after adding the new one.
- Do my first step, close Visual Studio delete Bin & Obj folders and relaunch VS.

Answer (score 0):

Found that when reinstalling the app, my phone would use a backup it automatically did on my Google Drive.

I had to delete the backup, and then it was working fine.

Comment: You could consider adding `android:allowBackup="false"` in the manifest for debug builds.